# Spotify Error 401 even though I, supposedly, have access_token (Python)

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, spotify

```
import requests
import base64
    
# Request an access token
def request_access_token():
    AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'

    # POST
    auth_response = requests.post(AUTH_URL, {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': "<client ID>",
        'client_secret': "<client Secret>",
    })

    # convert the response to JSON
    auth_response_data = auth_response.json()

    # save the access token
    print(auth_response_data)
    access_token = auth_response_data['access_token']

    return access_token

# Check if the access token is valid
def check_access_token_validity(access_token):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    response = requests.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", headers=headers)
    print(response)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Run the code
access_token = request_access_token()

if access_token:
    if check_access_token_validity(access_token):
        print("Access token is valid.")
    else:
        print("Access token is not valid.")
else:
    print("Could not request access token.")
```

I get a "access_token" but it doesn't work. It gives Error 401. I also got the same issue in javascript. I tried everything and I dont know what is wrong. Here's the output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyrGS.png)

Which shows that I did recieve a token. But when I try to check it's validity, it is [Invalid 401]. I have also rotated my client secret and same issue. Both Client ID and Client Secret are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/), your access token request is different

Try this

```
import requests
import base64

client_id = 'CLIENT_ID';
client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET';

response = requests.post(
    'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    data={'grant_type':'client_credentials'},
    headers={'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.urlsafe_b64encode((CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET).encode())},
)
```

Comment: The response is [200] but the token I received is the same one I had previously. My check_access_token_validity() still returns a response [401]. Is my validity check wrong? I am just confused since this very access_token couldn't be used in my javascript either. Maybe I'm messing up both my codes.

Comment: if you use the `access_token` received, [here](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-current-user/)..are you still getting 401?

Comment: It's the same token. Initially no. But when I pressed "get token" and tick "user-read-email" and "user-read-private" scope, I can now. At least now I can do it manually. Just need to figure out if I can specify the scopes in the code. Thanks.

Comment: check the scopes for your `client_credentials`...the generated `access_token` should work...since you are using `Client Credentials Flow`, the `access_token` can directly be used as in [docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/use-access-token/)

Comment: Thank you, I think where I went wrong is grant_type and the scope of each authorization.